# Having difficulties upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04 after katoolin messed things up

Tags: upgrade, 15.10

I recently removed "**katoolin**" from my computer because it messed things up with all these *repos and changes to the system info.. and what not.

Well after removing it it obviously left quite a few changes to  system infos, repos etc.

If I do the `sudo update-manager -d` it'll scan but will display *"Failed to 
download repository information"*

I can't go to Software and Updates in the settings to change repos because when I click it nothing happens.

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: With only this to go one  I would make a backup of the personal data and re-install and never look at katoolin ever again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

and comments all or replace it with the official one:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu